# Domoticz virtual sensor: how to set initial value

Tags: domoticz

I have a device that reads the P1 port of a smart meter. I have created a virtual sensor for the smart meter and, through a simple shell script, I can set the meter readings in Domoticz.  This works well.

However, for the devices (both electricity and gas), I get a large peak of consumption on the first period. That is because the virtual sensor is initialized with the values of 0 for all the counters.  This gives a peak that makes the graphs unusable.

Is there a way to initialize the meter reading on a non-zero value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domoticz uses an sqlite3 database. With `sqlite3 domoticz.db '.dump' > domo.dump`, you can get a complete dump of the database.  Searching for the index of the meter, I found the initial value (for the gas meter:)

```
 INSERT INTO Meter VALUES(1093,0,0,'2022-03-24 18:00:00');
```

Removing that row from the `Meter` table did the trick.